# How do I set pdf file name in windows.open() using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I have generated the PDF, but when the pdf is opened in a new tab, the name is changed with some random alphanumeric numbers like this "98d49355-2a77-497c-a064-ccd72ed1e3df".

`

```
 html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
                console.log(pdf.output('bloburl'));
                window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
                
            });
```

`
[image: pdf image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code :**

```
 html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
                console.log(pdf.output('bloburl'));
                var newWindow= window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
                newWindow.document.title = "YOUR PDF NAME HERE!";
            });
```